Wires reversed and one ground cut short, but plug-in outlet tester reads wiring correct
I have been testing all of my outlets with a plug-in tester.  All are 3-prong, and as far as I know all of the wiring is from the 60's and was supposed to be grounded.
I checked a series of outlets in my basement; the first outlet in the string read missing ground.
The second found no fault.  The 3 downstream from there had no ground.
The second outlet was very loose, and when I shut off the breaker and opened it up, I found that the black and white wires were reversed in the outgoing wire.  In addition, the outgoing ground wire had been cut off back at the wiring jacket, so the incoming wire was attached to the grounding screw, but the outgoing wire was not grounded.
Why would this outlet read no faults?
I will call an electrician, but I want to understand more about what this could mean and the possible scope of the problem first.

Keep in mind that it's very easy to fool those 3-light testers by jumpering on the receptacle from neutral to ground.  This will fool the tester even if hot and neutral were actually reversed, which would energize the metal chassis of anything plugged into it!  If you're seeing cut-rate work inside the place such as cutting off ground wires they hated, there is no substitute to opening up every box and inspecting by hand. It could all be a lie, and then, you would have recourse on the seller or his insurer for deception. (not in seller disclosures).

It sounds like all the incoming wires to the second outlet were connected properly, so that explains why the tester showed no faults.  The outgoing black and white reversed would have no bearing on the test results for that outlet, however it should make the downstream outlets test as hot/neutral reversed assuming a ground is available as @BartvanIngenSchenau points out. But since the ground is unavailable that would then explain a lack of the tester indicating hot/neutral reversed in the downstream outlets.
An alternative explanation for lack of the tester indicating hot/neutral reversed in the downstream outlets would be that the black and white wires are reversed again at the next outlet in the chain.  But that probably doesn't apply in this case.

A hot - neutral reverse can only be detected if you can compare them to ground, so the absence of a (connected) ground connector masks that fault in the downstream outlets.

Ah yes, good point @BartvanIngenSchenau

Yes, even worse, if they genuinely crossed hot and neutral, and then bootlegged socket neutral to ground, the 3-light tester would read correct and the ground would be energized at 120V, as would be the metal chassis of anything plugged into it.

The color of the wires doesn't actually DO anything, so if they happen to connect it right, it'll "work", but it is definitely not to code if someone inspects it.
Since you're trying to fix it, it is best to properly wire it up so that someone doesn't die. If they expect a wire to be ground but it is live, then it's not a good situation to be in.
This is also the reason why I religiously test electrical circuits when I work on it.  It's a habit that I test the wires before every touch, so that I never have to think about it. Saved me once already when some weird stuff happened downstream and fed the circuit that I was working on.
